# What does raddr and rport represent in an ICE candidate?

Tags: webrtc, nat, sdp, ice

Take this ICE candidate as an example
`a=candidate:1853887674 1 udp 1518280447 47.61.61.61 36768 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.196 rport 36768 generation 0`.

What does the raddr and rport represent? Also, what if the typ is `relay`, would that have any effect on it?

Answer (score 3):

raddr and rport are for debugging purpose. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245#appendix-B.3 explains the purpose.

For serverreflexive candidates, raddr/rport allow you figuring out which local port (host candidate) is associated with this candidate. For relay candidates it will do the same, but for a serverreflexive candidate.

Answer (score 0):

As Philipp kindly pointed out, the documentation shows that raddr probably stands for relative address and rport stands for relative port, ie. the local ip address and local port. Also, if the type is "relay", it means the connection is being made through a TURN server.

Comment: old link is dead: https://web.archive.org/web/20191013033718/https://temasys.io/webrtc-ice-sorcery/